# What is causing this JSON to have an unexpected EOF?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get a JSON from an API. I know the API works, because I can get the data by making a call through Postman, but when I try to get the data in my app I get "JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF".

The API call used is basically identical to another call made elsewhere in the app to a different endpoint, so I have no clue what would be causing the problem.

Code:

```
const DrinkPopup = (props) => {

  const [drinkDetails,setDrinkDetails] = useState([])

  fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=' + props.drink)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => setDrinkDetails(json.drinks))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))


  return(
    <Modal isVisible={props.modalVisible}
    onBackdropPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}} //allows closing modal by tapping outside it or back button
    onBackButtonPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}} 
    animationIn={"slideInUp"}>  
      <View style={styles.infocard}>
          <View style={styles.titleBox}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>{drinkDetails.idDrink}</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>


  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, like

```
<Text style={styles.header}>
  {drinkDetails && drinkDetails.idDrink
    ? JSON.stringify(drinkDetails.idDrink)
    : "No record"}
</Text>
```

Comment: I get the no record error message, but I know that I shouldn't be. The item the code should be looking for definitely exists.

Comment: @Swystem  what are you getting in response `json.drinks` ?

Comment: It seems like the fetch is running too often, but it's giving me whatever drink that is selected, just repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Try put your fetch in an `async` function and call that probably in a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Is there any documentation available to show me how to do that? I'm trying to figure it out, but I must be looking for the wrong terms. I'm still pretty new to React Native.